# What is the recommended method to encrypt the home directory in Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

Installing Ubuntu to a new Notebook, I was surprised that I wasn't offered the option to encrypt the home directory any more.

I found some vague information that Ubuntu dropped ecryptfs support a while ago in favor of complete disc encryption with LUKS. For my use case it isn't desirable to encrypt the whole device as I aiming only to protect the data for unauthorized access in case the machine gets lost or stolen. No super sensitive data are involved and no hostile government agency (as far as I know) and I cant afford an extra password dialog.

So my question is simple: What is the recommended method to encrypt home directory in Ubuntu 21.04?

Am I for some reason discouraged to use ecryptfs?

Can I safely use the old method described bellow?

First install the packages ecryptfs-utils and rsync:

```
sudo apt install ecryptfs-utils rsync lsof
```

Then load the ecryptfs kernel module:

```
sudo modprobe ecryptfs
```

The user whose home directory you want to encrypt MUST NOT be logged in. For example, you can be logged as root in a tty.

Then run as root:

```
ecryptfs-migrate-home -u <username>
```

Comment: *" I cant afford an extra password dialog"* - if you encrypted the whole system drive, you could enter that passphrase once at boot and then automatically log your user in. Although if you only log out later and don't shutdown, you wouldn't want just anyone to log in automatically later... I wonder if auto-login can only be enabled once at boot, and not for subsequent logouts

Answer (score 9):

The recommended way to encrypt on Ubuntu/Linux these days is indeed LUKS, whether for separate containers or whole partitions.

I am doing exactly what you want to do, encrypting and mounting a separate partition as my `/home/username` (`$HOME`, `/home/$USER`) drive. Below are the steps involved.

**WARNING:** Doing this will destroy any data on the partition you use!

1. Create the encrypted partition:

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdXX
   ```

   where you replace sdXX with the actual device number of the partition you want to encrypt. Choose your password when prompted. This will create the LUKS header at the beginning of the partiton, nothing else. You can verify that the header has been correctly formatted by LUKS by doing

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdXX
   ```
2. Map the encrypted container:

   You can replace `c1` by whatever name you want:

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdXX c1
   ```

   **Optional**: Wipe the partition:

   ```
   sudo cat /dev/zero > /dev/mapper/c1
   ```

   will wipe the partition with random data, making sure nothing that may have been on it before can be reconstructed. This may take a while.
3. Create a filesystem in the mapped container:

   Here I use ext4:

   ```
   sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/c1
   ```
4. Update your /etc/crypttab file:

   Your crypttab should contain a line like

   ```
   cryptHome     UUID=12345678-abcd-1234-5678-1234567890ab    none    luks,timeout=30
   ```

   with the UUID of the device you just encrypted above (i.e. the `/dev/sdXX` device). You can find it out by using e.g. `lsblk -f` (it should say "crypto_LUKS" under FSTYPE in the output).
5. Update your /etc/fstab file:

   Finally, your fstab should contain a line like

   ```
   /dev/mapper/cryptHome         /home/username    ext4   defaults    0    2
   ```

   to mount the decrypted partition in your filesystem. The mapped name (cryptHome) must match the one you defined in the crypttab. Replace `username` by the name of the actual user.

   You could also mount it under /home, but then you will have all user's home directories in one encrypted drive - that means all of them need to know the partition's password to open it on boot.

#### Final remarks

With these steps Ubuntu will ask you to unlock the partition on every boot, before the login screen for the user.

There is no problem to set up the system with a default `/home/username` directory, and then mount an encrypted partition over it. To migrate an existing home directory, mount the mapped drive (`/dev/mapper/c1` in this example) somewhere temporary after Step 3 and copy over the data before rebooting.

[This](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) is an excellent resource if you want to know more about how LUKS works.

Comment: Doesn't the installer offer to encrypt a separate /home partition like this, only for all users instead of just one? Can these instructions be modified to use a (large) file as a single user's encrypted home, instead of a whole partition? Maybe just with an initial `fallocate` & `losetup` before luksFormat, and the filename instead of UUID in crypttab... That could be much more convenient than re-partitioning

Comment: The reason I wrote this guide is that it is independent of how the installer decides to work this season, and is pretty universal even for other distributions. I guess you could use a file container instead of a partition, however I do not really see the advantage and have never tried doing that at boot time, so try at your own risk. A guide for encrypted file containers is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1243586/907096)

Comment: That's true, this question is because the installer stopped doing things it used to. FYI, cryptsetup (at lest v2.6.1) can set up & use a loop device on it's own now, just specifying a file for format & open works.

Answer (score -1):

1. During the installation from the USB stick you get to choose if you want to install on the whole harddrive or not, you can choose the option "something else" where you can choose which partitions you want to use.
2. In the partitioning dialog, you must create a small 800MB partition for `/boot` that must be formatted in ext2
3. Then create another partition of the type "Physical Volume for Encryption".

   Make sure, you have another USB-Stick or such, where you can store the encryption-recovery-Key during the install process.
4. inside the encrypted container you can then create a root partition for your whole system `/`.

(I am not sure, how to create a swap partition there as well as recommended, since there is no option to create new partitions inside the encrypted container)