# Mount LUKS encrypted partition at login

Tags: mount, encryption, luks, ecryptfs, pam

I would like to mount a LUKS partition on login. The solutions I have found involve using either:

- a LUKS passphrase that is equal to the user's password, or
- a keyfile that is stored in the HOME folder

I am looking for a solution that:

- allows a LUKS passphrase to be different from the user's password, and
- since my HOME folder is not encrypted, does not leave a keyfile accessible.

Is such as solution available?

I remember that when Ubuntu created a ~/.Private directory using ecryptfs this was possible; how was it done? Can't the same be done with LUKS?

Comment: What is your actual requirement? Are you a single user on your machine and do you want to have a certain partition unlocked when you start up your PC? In that case you can set up the partition to unlock at boot time like explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335006/what-is-the-recommended-method-to-encrypt-the-home-directory-in-ubuntu-21-04/1335327#1335327). Or do you have a server that is used by multiple users and each one wants to unlock a certain partition on login, but not at boot? In that case a simple script that is executed after login could do the job.

Comment: @Sebastian, doesn't the solution explained in the link you refereed to require the LUKS passphrase and the user's password to be the same?

Comment: No, it does not! I am doing it like that myself, with two different passwords. The OS will ask the passphrase for the partition to be unlocked first, then it will proceed to the login screen, but both are completely separate.

Comment: @Sebastian, "The OS will ask the passphrase" at each login? I wanted to mount it automatically at login, and now I see the question wasn't clear about this point.

Comment: No, the passphrase to unlock the partition is only asked when you boot. After that you can logout and login and it will only ask the user's login password.