# Encrypt the home directory in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: encryption, 22.04

I am upgrading my home server with **Ubuntu 22.04** and I was surprised to find that there is no option to encrypt home directory as it was in **Ubuntu 16.04**. I could only choose either to use `LVM` and encrypt the entire partition or to not encrypt at all.

Encrypting the entire partition is ok for me, however, since my server is headless, I have to be able to log in into it remotely with `ssh`. There are definitely solutions for this like setting up `dropbear` and `busybox`, but this is too much hassle for me to achieve the goal.

Alternatively, I could create a separate partition for home directory and encrypt it with `LUKS`, however, it will not be a dynamic partition and space for it will be allocated initially. Moreover, it might be a hassle to extend it.

Another idea that comes to my mind is to use a file container and encrypt is with `LUKS` as described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243532/create-encrypted-file-container-without-installing-additional-applications) question. The container can be extended if needed. Again, this solution looks kind of exotic to me. I am looking for best practices or a common and widely used approach to this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: There is not even an option to use a separate home partition. It's not recommended to do so. You will have to set this up manually if this is what you want.  Generally you have to set up full disk encryption during system installation. It can be very convoluted to try to set up encryption after-the-fact, but you should be able to find solutions by searching for whatever you would like to do.

Comment: @Nmath When talking about a separate home partition I meant creating it manually, yes. My question is how do professional administrators address such a question - busybox and dropbear? separate partition? file container?

Comment: Maybe I am confused about your question because you seem to already know the solution-- that you need to create the partition manually. You've also already went into your choices in your question, so it's not clear what you are unclear about. I also don't know what what you mean by "how do professional administrators address such a question".  What question? How to encrypt data at rest? How to use a separate home partition?

Comment: which of these approaches they stick to

Comment: ... I'm sorry but I don't follow... Can you answer my questions?  Maybe you are just looking for "best practices" or opinions instead of asking how to perform this task?  Are you looking for opinions on how to organize your files and protect your data? If so, Ask Ubuntu is not the right place to ask for opinions. See: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic -- If you want to start a discussion or try to get a general survey on what people consider best practices, you can ask discussion based and opinion based questions on Ubuntu Forums.

Comment: *I have to be able to log in into it remotely with ssh*... Your whole question (and misunderstanding) seems to stem from the believe you need to do something else because of the full drive encryption vs. the old encrypted home when actually there's no difference at all even vs no encryption. What you need to understand is that when accessing it remotely your server must be running already therefore all partitions are already decrypted. Please read the answer to understand what encryption is meant to protect users from.

Answer (score 3):

## Best Practice: No Encryption

The option to encrypt the `/home/$USER/` folder in Ubuntu was deprecated due to security issues. In other words, this old option was not secure.

You describe your computer as a "home server." Servers typically keep shared files (file servers) or web pages (web servers) in locations other than in the home folder. For example, the location of files in a SAMBA server may be in `/srv/samba/share/`. Similarly, the files for a web server may be in `/var/www/`. In all these cases encrypting the home folder does not do any good.

A server, whether it is a home or for commercial use, is always on. An encrypted partition or an encrypted "whole disk" is only encrypted when it is at rest. That is, when the server is running the partition is at unencrypted state. If you are worried that someone will break into your home and walk away with your home server (after turning it off) and then try to turn it back on again at at the thief's layer, to steal your private information then disk/partition encryption makes sense. But you may invest in a good lock for your door.

If you are worried about someone may remotely hack into your running home server and steal your private information, then disk/partition encryption makes zero sense. You may want to properly configure your home router's and the home server's firewall, and look at other ways to secure your server from remote hacks.

Hope this helps

Comment: I fully understand the concepts you are mentioning. The reason for encrypting `home` is that there are credentials (encryption keys for drives and so on) that should not be exposed once someone took out the drives and tries to see their content. Previously, for Ubuntu 16.04 that could be solved out of the box. I see from your reply that this option is discontinued. If there are no other out-of-box solutions, I will create an encrypted container and put all sensitive data in there. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. Sometimes I take out my drives, move them across PCs or carry in laptop. Full encryption is difficult to manage considering dual boot and a need to upgrade Linux from time to time. I need to secure my most private data while the PC is off and Bitlocker-like partition encryption makes most sense. It's not ideal but it seems like a good compromise, as compared to buying a good door lock ;-). @Mishgun_  did you eventually use encrypted container or did you find another suitable solution?

Comment: @Alan hello Alan, sorry for a late reply. I eventually ended up using an encrypted container.

Comment: @Mishgun_ Feel free to answer your own question and detail how you configured the container, if you used a password, or a key-file, set it to decrypt automatically on login etc. You have already provided a link in the question. Note, an answer with just a link is not sufficient. Then accept your answer by clicking on the gray check mark next to it and turn it green. This will help others like Alan.

Answer (score 1):

This video should help.
the issue is not a thief, it is another user that is attempting to access private data in another users home folder, or a compromised user accessing another users home folder data.
https://youtu.be/ftMFTf4I-Ig

Basically download and install:

`sudo apt install ecryptfs-utils cryptsetup`

From **another TEMP user** with **sudo ability**, run the command:

`sudo ecryptfs-migrate-home -u <user-to-Encrypt-Home>`

Then log into that user you just migrated and run:

`ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase`

Then delete the temp folder that was created for the user

*< User-to-Encrypt-Home > .RandomCharacters*

Comment: Consider summarizing the content here so that this is no longer a link-only answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1252317)